# keras 16 phantom values are taken from somewhere that do not allow neural networks to learn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am creating a neural network for colorization of photos , but out of nowhere 16 values appear that do not allow neural networks to learn .

```
#%% import libiaries
from keras.layers import *
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator,array_to_img,img_to_array,load_img
from skimage import io, color
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from PIL import Image

#%% import train images
# images = [
#     io.imread(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\dog.jpg'),
#     io.imread(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\dog2.jpg'),
#     io.imread(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\family.jpg'),
#     io.imread(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\frukty-korzina-ananas-kivi-iabloko-grusha.jpg'),
#     io.imread(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\hinh-nen-trai-cay-dep-2.jpg'),
#     io.imread(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\humans.jpg'),
#     io.imread(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\maxresdefault_live.jpg'),
#     io.imread(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\maxresdefault.jpg'),
#     io.imread(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\Narezannyj-apelsin-1.jpg')
# ]
images = [
    Image.open(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\dog.jpg'),
    Image.open(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\dog2.jpg'),
    Image.open(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\family.jpg'),
    Image.open(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\frukty-korzina-ananas-kivi-iabloko-grusha.jpg'),
    Image.open(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\hinh-nen-trai-cay-dep-2.jpg'),
    Image.open(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\humans.jpg'),
    Image.open(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\maxresdefault_live.jpg'),
    Image.open(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\maxresdefault.jpg'),
    Image.open(r'D:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\data\Narezannyj-apelsin-1.jpg')
]
# img.show()
#%% image process function
def image2LabTables(image):
    image = image.resize((1280,720), Image.BILINEAR)
    image = np.array(image, dtype=float)
    size = image.shape
    lab = color.rgb2lab(1.0/255*image)
    X,y = lab[:,:,0], lab[:,:,1:]

    y = y / 128
    X = X.reshape(1,size[0],size[1],1)
    y = y.reshape(1,size[0],size[1],2)
    return X,y,size


# %%
image2LabTables(images[0])


# %% create model
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    InputLayer(input_shape=(None,None,1)),
    Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same',strides = 2),
    Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same',strides = 2),
    Conv2D(512,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    Conv2D(512,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same',strides = 2),
    Conv2D(1024,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    Conv2D(1024,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same',strides = 2),
    Conv2D(2048,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    Conv2D(2048,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same',strides = 2),
    Conv2D(4096,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    Conv2D(2048,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    Conv2D(1024,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(512,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'),
    Conv2D(2,(3,3),activation = 'tanh',padding = 'same'),
    UpSampling2D((2, 2))
])

# %%
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss='mse')

# %%
for _ in range(50):
    for i in images:
        X,y,size = image2LabTables(i)
        model.fit(X,y,batch_size = 1)
```

but e gives me

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\Coding\Projects\Mini_projects\Playground\colorizator\main.py in ()
      87 for i in images:
      88     X,y,size = image2LabTables(i)
----> 89     model.fit(X,y,batch_size = 1)

File c:\Users\adamy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file2pjbbjjd.py:15, in outer_factory..inner_factory..tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "c:\Users\adamy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1330, in train_function  *
...
    File "c:\Users\adamy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 1470, in mean_squared_error
        return backend.mean(tf.math.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true), axis=-1)

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 736 and 720 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential_6/up_sampling2d_34/resize/ResizeNearestNeighbor, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [1,736,1280,2], [1,720,1280,2].
```

Please help me

I tried to train the neural network piece by piece (you will find this in a very strange for algorithm at the end). I tried to make an input shape in the dimension in which he asks, but it doesn't work out in any way